# Is a Spinner right for this UI?

Tags: icons, android

On Android, I want to create a drop-down menu of buttons activated on touch on the right of the screen, with a 'close' button to return to original closed state. Is a Spinner the appropriate UI element?

Comment: As ever - it depends. Could you add a mock-up of the screen? The added context might help guide the answers.

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

A spinner increments/decrements a value or walks through a list of values.  It only shows one value at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard control (at least for a fullscreen dropdown menu) would be a reasonably large tap area with a small circle-and-arrow icon like the one next to the radio buttons here:

http://psdho.me/buttons/google-android-grafic-user-interface-psd-file.html.

The close button would probably go under the scrollable area with the menu items. Try looking under Settings on an Android phone.

Comment: Without having drilled down to the exact pertinent info, you might find this useful: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html